# android emulator for google nexus 7?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to set up android emulator which will be simulate the device google nexus 7. It has got 7 inches display and resolution 1280x800.

What the number is properly value for monitor dpi? Is this value equivalent of abstracted LCD density in the hardware part?

[image]
[image]

Comment: AFAIK: Monitor dpi is your pc's monitor dpi, not the device one. All options in second picture are about your monitor, the device options go into the hardware properties in the first picture

Comment: @zapl is right.  Also, Google would consider the Nexus 7 as a Medium DPI(240ish), if you were wondering.  This is contrast to the Galaxy Nexus which is Extra High(320)

Comment: @Jameo The Nexus 7 is actually TVDPI (213dpi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a answer for others with similar obscurities about properly settings of a display in android emulator.

So I set **abstracted LCD density** to value **213**. It is the default value of Nexus 7. Because of this value nexus is not able shows full tablet mode. This value is specific for every device.

Next I set **resolution** to **1280x800** and save it. Then I click on start emulator and set next values about monitor.

I use **15.4 inches monitor** with **resolution 1680x1050 px**. Firstly I set **screen size** of tablet (**7 inches**) and then **monitor dpi**. When you click on the question mark, it will show you new window with the **screen size** and **resolution**. These values are values of your pc monitor. When you fill these values, it compute your monitor dpi. For me it is **129**. And finally I start emulator.